# Azurite local tables aren't permenant when checked with Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azurite, azure-storage-explorer

I installed azurite locally to use it for my personal app development. I always launch it with the same set of ports for blob/queue/table.

I created a table and entered some data and then I checked with az storage explorer it was all good, but after a while the table just disappears. Are the tables in azurite temporary that I have created and enter mock on every start?

I'd expect that the data created in azurite stays.

Comment: This should not happen. What is the command you are using to launch Azurite?

Comment: Please edit to show more details about how you're starting the emulator, how you're using it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved by it self after a few restart of the PC.